# Approach needed: Collect sql results and use result field as Input for next query

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have used my server-sided script engine to follow a "Process"->"Document"-link-chain, that has the following construction:

"Process Step A" -> "Document A", "Process Step B" -> "Document B" ... "Process Step N" -> "Document N"

The script engine did the following SQL Statement calls until the last result set is empty:

[image: The task is to make a stored procedure]

Task: I want to replace this with a stored prcoedure, that gets (like in the example) the ID 'SE-SOP-53' and returns ONE result set.

I want to implement a stored procedure like this:

```
IF OBJECT_ID ( 'dbo.sp_PreviousAcitivites', 'P' ) IS NOT NULL   
DROP PROCEDURE dbo.sp_PreviousAcitivites;  
GO  
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sp_PreviousAcitivites   
@StartPoint nvarchar(50)
AS   
SET NOCOUNT ON;  
DECLARE @document_id VARCHAR(max)

SELECT * 
FROM [document_to_process] 
WHERE process_step_id=@StartPoint
AND direction='I' 
GO

dbo.sp_PreviousAcitivites 'SE-SOP-53'
```

The result of that should be ONE result set but not like in the screenshot several result sets.

Can someone give me a good approach how to iterate over such RESULT Sets, Collect them and Stop Iterating when a result is empty?

Comment: I would suggest RECURSION. As for getting one and only one result each query, you need to add a suitable condition (to the WHERE clause).

Comment: Do i have to build the SQL as String? I would have to select alternating WHERE process_step_id=@StartPoint AND direction='I' and additionally WHERE document_id=@StartPoint AND direction='O'

Comment: Well, since you have only two alternatives for the query, I would add a parameter to the function indicating which option to use. Then, within the body, a simple IF - THEN - ELSE statement will use the correct one. This way, you would not be using DYNAMIC SQL which has certain effect on performance.

Comment: Hi thank you for your suggestions. I have posted my solution on this, can you please tell me if there are ways to make it more elegant or to be more performat?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to implement such a function now, i did it without recursion.

I only have one problem: I would need a DO...WHILE... Loop instead of a while loop because i have to initialize the while loop in which condition i ask if the last result was empty. How can i do this more elegant?

There are some parts i think about:

1.) I always DELETE the @lastResult Table Variable on each WHILE-Iteration

2.) I have to initialize the WHILE Loop because i do not have a DO .... WHILE ...

3.) @lastResult and @collectedResult have the same table declaration ... can i make s.th. like DECLARE @lastResult, @collectedResult TABLE ...

```
IF OBJECT_ID ( 'dbo.sp_PreviousAcitivites', 'P' ) IS NOT NULL   
DROP PROCEDURE dbo.sp_PreviousAcitivites;  
GO  
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sp_PreviousAcitivites   
@StartPoint nvarchar(50)
AS   

SET NOCOUNT ON;  

DECLARE @lastResult TABLE (document_id VARCHAR(30), document_name VARCHAR(100), direction VARCHAR(1), process_step_id VARCHAR(30), process_step VARCHAR(100))
DECLARE @collectedResult TABLE (document_id VARCHAR(30), document_name VARCHAR(100), direction VARCHAR(1), process_step_id VARCHAR(30), process_step VARCHAR(100))
DECLARE @nextDirection VARCHAR(1)
DECLARE @nextSelectionID VARCHAR(30)
DECLARE @maxResultCount INT
DECLARE @resultCount INT

SET @maxResultCount=50
SET @resultCount=0
SET @nextDirection='I'
SET @nextSelectionID=@StartPoint

INSERT INTO @lastResult
SELECT TOP 1 document_id, document_name, direction, process_step_id, process_step  
FROM [document_to_process] 
WHERE process_step_id=@nextSelectionID
AND direction=@nextDirection 

WHILE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM @lastResult) AND @resultCount < @maxResultCount
BEGIN

    IF @nextDirection='I' 
    BEGIN
        SELECT @nextSelectionID=process_step_id FROM @lastResult

        DELETE FROM @lastResult

        INSERT INTO @lastResult
        SELECT TOP 1 document_id, document_name, direction, process_step_id, process_step  
        FROM [document_to_process] 
        WHERE process_step_id=@nextSelectionID
        AND direction=@nextDirection 

        SET @nextDirection='O' 
    END 
    ELSE 
    BEGIN
        SELECT @nextSelectionID=document_id FROM @lastResult

        DELETE FROM @lastResult

        INSERT INTO @lastResult
        SELECT TOP 1 document_id, document_name, direction, process_step_id, process_step  
        FROM [document_to_process] 
        WHERE document_id=@nextSelectionID
        AND direction=@nextDirection 

        SET @nextDirection='I' 
    END

    SET @resultCount=@resultCount+1

    INSERT INTO @collectedResult(document_id, document_name, direction, process_step_id, process_step) 
    SELECT document_id, document_name, direction, process_step_id, process_step FROM @lastResult
END

SELECT * FROM @collectedResult
GO

dbo.sp_PreviousAcitivites 'SE-SOP-53'
```

Comment: Elegance... This is a very subjective thing. The only remark on this is that you should try and make your code more readable (it is not a disaster as many people sometimes post, but there is room for improvement). Secondly, **recursion** is a very good thing when properly and carefully used. And yes, it would be more elegant in this particular case (at least to my eyes).

Comment: One more thing: If my comments served you, you may consider up-voting them (so I get some additions to my reputation :-)).